# Fixed FAB button inside a scrollable RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

I have a scrollable RelativeLayout that contain some EditText, ImageView and others View elements...

```
<ScrollView...
    <RelativeLayout
       <TextView...
       <ImageView...
       <Button...
       ...
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So now I want to insert a FAB button inside of it so I can scroll all the layout (EditText, ImageView, etc) but with the FAB that is fixed in bottom|right position of the screen. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your layout should have such structure:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/svContent"
       .....
   </ScrollView>

   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/fab"
       .....
       app:layout_anchor="@id/svContent"
       app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And note attributes `layout_anchor` and `layout_anchorGravity` there.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much, It works but It causes some performance troubles...                                                                                               "Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main read."                                                                                              How can I manage this situation in this case?

Comment: You can try to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) instead of `ScrollView` and specify scrolling behavior for it

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet for FAB

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    android:src="@android:drawable/icon" />
```

This will make the FAB stable at bottom if relative layout height is match parent.